# Swig: using c++ STL complex in Python

Tags: python, c++, swig

I want to use c++ complex type in python. I tried the following Swig interface file:

```
%module example
%include <std_complex.i>
%template(complexf) std::complex<float>;
```

It returned this error:

```
example.i:3: Error: Template 'complex' undefined.
```

If I include c++ header file  manually,

```
%module example
%include <std_complex.i>

%include "/usr/include/c++/7/complex"
%template(complexf) std::complex<float>;
```

I would get another error:

```
/usr/include/c++/7/complex:50: Error: Syntax error in input(1).
```

So I am wondering how to use c++ complex with SWIG correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std_complex.i` already includes enough definition to use `std::complex<float>`:

```
%module example
%include <std_complex.i>

%inline %{
using complexf = std::complex<float>;
complexf func(complexf a, complexf b)
{
    return a + b;
}
%}
```

Usage (compiled with VS2015):

```
>>> import example
>>> example.func(1+2j,3-4j)
(4-2j)
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it.